# How to dye hair without hair dye

Tags: personal-care, hair

I need to dye my hair **temporarily**, but I don't have any hair dye. I need a method that safe and works on different colors and lengths of hair (I have friends who need to dye their hair too). I would also like the method to be quick and also easy to wash out. Bonus points for a method that can have different colors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Use Kool-Aid

https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=kool+aid+hair+dye

> Directions
>   1. Be very sure to use UNSWEETENED.
>   2. Mix one packet of Kool-Aid with the water in a pot.
>   3. Heat until boiling, stirring.
>   4. Remove from heat and cool to a temperature that is warm but not hot.
>   5. Dip as much hair as possible into the mix.
>   6. Then, with your head over the pot, ladle the kool-aid over the hair.

## Multiple colors

Use a different pot with different color, and carefully dye with the other color.  If your hair is long enough, use a pony tail so you can separate the colors more easily.

Nice DIY article: http://hairstyles.ninja/tag/how-to-dye-your-hair-using-kool-aid-official-blog-for-

[image]

## How temporary?

It lasts a couple of weeks, depending on how often you wash your hair.  You can speed it up by soaking it in a [solution](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Kool-Aid-out-of-Hair#Baking_Soda_and_Vinegar) of **baking soda and vinegar**.

Comment: What do they _put_ in these things?!

Answer (score 1):

## **Temporary Hair Colour Spray**

You can consider using the temporary hair color spray, they are availble in many colours in the many online stores such as Amazon, eBay, walmart, etc and they are washable. :)

They are pretty cheap and easy to use as compared to the permenent hair dye.

You can learn more here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eF6JJ7Smfkg

[image: Temporary Hair Colour Spray]

Image from: http://www.temporaryhaircolorspray.com/hair-color-spray-washable/

Comment: Note: Some of these sprays are terrible. Check a few different brands to see which you like. I got some cheap stuff for Halloween last year, and it seemed to be (bad) spray paint mixed with (bad) hair spray. Clumpy, very stiff, and hard to wash from both hair and skin.

Answer (score 1):

### Crepe Paper

It's easy and goes away after one or two washes. You just have to wet it and rub it against your hair. It comes in a variety of colors, is extremely cheap and very easy to find!

Answer (score 1):

### Home Remedies

I have a few home remedies.

1. You can use beetroot juice to give your hair a nice reddish tinge.
2. Applying a coffee mix helps to darken your hair.
3. Henna gives your hair a nice mahogany shade (henna comes in different shades so you better have a look at the label before purchasing some. )

p.s: The effectiveness of the above mentioned home remedies vary with the natural shade of your hair. The lighter your hair colour is, the more effective the remedies are.

Comment: Did you miss the bit about *temporary*? At least henna is permanent and I strongly suspect the other two to be similarly permanent.

Comment: Henna isn't permanent.  It wears off with every wash. The maximum it stays is for about a month and you have to reapply it.

Comment: And since these do not have any chemical enhancements and are natural, they don't stay on for a longer period of time.